# PredictionIO UniversalRecommender elasticsearch error

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, elasticsearch, predictionio, recommendation-engine

I'm using the Universal Recommender that comes with Prediction.io and am getting the following error when I run the `./examples/integration-test` script (found [**here**](http://actionml.com/docs/ur_quickstart)).

```
[INFO] [ContextHandler] Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6ec63f8{/jobs,null,UNAVAILABLE,@Spark}
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Elasticsearch client configuration detected, check your pio-env.sh forproper configuration settings
        at com.actionml.EsClient$$anonfun$client$2.apply(EsClient.scala:86)
        at com.actionml.EsClient$$anonfun$client$2.apply(EsClient.scala:86)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at com.actionml.EsClient$.client$lzycompute(EsClient.scala:85)
        at com.actionml.EsClient$.client(EsClient.scala:85)
        at com.actionml.EsClient$.createIndex(EsClient.scala:174)
        at com.actionml.EsClient$.hotSwap(EsClient.scala:271)
        at com.actionml.URModel.save(URModel.scala:82)
        at com.actionml.URAlgorithm.calcAll(URAlgorithm.scala:367)
        at com.actionml.URAlgorithm.train(URAlgorithm.scala:295)
        at com.actionml.URAlgorithm.train(URAlgorithm.scala:180)
        at org.apache.predictionio.controller.P2LAlgorithm.trainBase(P2LAlgorithm.scala:49)
        at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine$$anonfun$18.apply(Engine.scala:690)
        at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine$$anonfun$18.apply(Engine.scala:690)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine$.train(Engine.scala:690)
        at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine.train(Engine.scala:176)
        at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CoreWorkflow$.runTrain(CoreWorkflow.scala:67)
        at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.main(CreateWorkflow.scala:251)
        at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CreateWorkflow.main(CreateWorkflow.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My config (`PredictionIO/conf/pio-env.sh`) looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

# PredictionIO Main Configuration
#
# This section controls core behavior of PredictionIO. It is very likely that
# you need to change these to fit your site.

# SPARK_HOME: Apache Spark is a hard dependency and must be configured.
# SPARK_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
SPARK_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6

POSTGRES_JDBC_DRIVER=$PIO_HOME/lib/postgresql-42.0.0.jar
MYSQL_JDBC_DRIVER=$PIO_HOME/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar

# ES_CONF_DIR: You must configure this if you have advanced configuration for
#              your Elasticsearch setup.
# ES_CONF_DIR=/opt/elasticsearch

# HADOOP_CONF_DIR: You must configure this if you intend to run PredictionIO
#                  with Hadoop 2.
# HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop

# HBASE_CONF_DIR: You must configure this if you intend to run PredictionIO
#                 with HBase on a remote cluster.
# HBASE_CONF_DIR=$PIO_HOME/vendors/hbase-1.0.0/conf

# Filesystem paths where PredictionIO uses as block storage.
PIO_FS_BASEDIR=$HOME/.pio_store
PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/engines
PIO_FS_TMPDIR=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/tmp

# PredictionIO Storage Configuration
#
# This section controls programs that make use of PredictionIO's built-in
# storage facilities. Default values are shown below.
#
# For more information on storage configuration please refer to
# http://predictionio.apache.org/system/anotherdatastore/

# Storage Repositories

# Default is to use PostgreSQL
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=PGSQL

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=PGSQL

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=PGSQL

# Storage Data Sources

# PostgreSQL Default Settings
# Please change "pio" to your database name in PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_URL
# Please change PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_USERNAME and
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_PASSWORD accordingly
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_TYPE=jdbc
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_USERNAME=pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_PASSWORD=pio

# MySQL Example
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_TYPE=jdbc
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/pio
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_USERNAME=pio
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_PASSWORD=pio

# Elasticsearch Example
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_PORTS=9200
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEMES=http
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/elasticsearch-5.5.2
# Optional basic HTTP auth
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=my-name
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=my-secret
# Elasticsearch 1.x Example
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTERNAME=<elasticsearch_cluster_name>
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_PORTS=9300
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/elasticsearch-1.7.6

# Local File System Example
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_LOCALFS_TYPE=localfs
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_LOCALFS_PATH=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/models

# HBase Example
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_TYPE=hbase
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/hbase-1.0.0

# AWS S3 Example
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_S3_TYPE=s3
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_S3_BUCKET_NAME=pio_bucket
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_S3_BASE_PATH=pio_model
```

I am trying to use PSQL for all three types of storage (meta, event, and model), so not sure why I'm being given an error RE elasticsearch?

Do I need to have elasticsearch running somewhere?

1. List item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feedback provided on the actionml-user group forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionml-user/9gPlf5iWDWQ

In summary - while predictionio provides many options for different data sources for the 3 "repositories", the universal recommender (UR) engine requires elasticsearch as the Metadata store. The event data repository is ideally set to HBASE (although I think I saw a post that someone got it to work with Postgres). The model repository isn't really used by UR, so that can also be configured to use LOCALFS which is the configuration I've successfully used.

Comment: I customized the universal recommender and make it work with ElasticSearch for both metadata and eventmodel but I'm trying to make work to have model work with ElasticSearch as well, any idea how to do this because I got an exception that not support it yet.
another question, this engine specify to explicitly user ElasticSearch as metadata!? and how to change?